# Service, but no WSDL

Tags: xml, web-services

I have to get data from a web service, but they do not publish a WSDL file. My SSIS component won't work without the WSDL.

Is it possible for me to create a WSDL file for someone else's Web Service?

Comment: What platform is running the SOAP service? Is it in-house or COTS?

Comment: In my case, it turned out to be a HTTP GET, not a web service.

Answer (score 2):

From the possibility perspective, of course it theoretically is. On the other hand, it is very tricky to create, and extremely prone to errors. First of all, do you have a representative set of messages for the service?

Answer (score 0):

Logically, you can create.

But, you should not do that.

1. Do you know all the messages of the services?
2. Do you know all the operations and methods offered by that service?
3. Do you know the number of arguments of the operations? Their data types? And the function return type?
4. Do you know namespace URI?
5. Are you prepared for any future change done by service developer?
6. Are you ready to constantly track the behavior of the service??

There are lots of loopholes in creating a WSDL of other's web service.

So my answer is: **You can... but not advisable.**